# Get full instance from URI in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

On POST I use the `obj_create` function to create a new instance of a workspace model. A workspace has an owner which is a Foreign field to a User. The data send from the client contains only a URI for the user of the form `"/api/v1/users/1/"`. How can I get the full instance from my database?

I have used `hydrate` and `get_via_uri` from the docs but it didn't work. Another possibility is to get the id of that user from the URI and query the database for the instance. However I am not sure of this is how I am supposed to do it (I am new to tastypie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documents are pretty clear on this: `full=True`

[http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.full)

Comment: Yes, but this means that on the client I'll get the full resource object for a user, which is something I don't want to do.

Comment: you could simply remove it again by overwriting the bundle?